# excel 2016 vba checking and changing sheets with multiple windows open of same instance

Tags: vba, excel

I've found quite a bit of information on working with multiple windows but not enough to get me over the line with this one.

Using Excel 2016 with multiple windows open how can use I use VBA to check which worksheet is open in each window?

As an example... 
The file is "Open File.xlsm"
It has sheets from "Sheet1" through "Sheet9"
There are 3 Windows open

How can I tell if "Sheet5" is open in any of the open windows?

```
Function CheckForSheet5() As Boolean

    Dim ExcelWindow as Window
    For Each ExcelWindow in Application.Windows

        ' I'm lost for ideas in here

    Next ExcelWindow

End Function
```

Subsequently how can I change which sheet is visible/activated within each window again using VBA? Do I need to cycle through by activating windows or is there another way?

**Context**
I'm developing a tool to help with budgeting and optimisation for the maintenance of a large fleet of vehicles. The tool has a large range of inputs all in different tables on different sheets (maintenance tasks, fuel rates, tyre usage, and so on...), an allocation table where equipment is turned on and off, and a range of output dashboards on different sheets.

The engaging team are all working with a minimum of 2, often 3 and up to 4 screens so we have set it up with the intent to use multiple windows within the same instance of Excel (the price of fuel is changed in 1 window and the output changes immediately in another).

Comment: As long as you use the same instance of Excel for each workbook, you can enumerate workbooks in the same way you enumerate worksheets. Forget Windows, you need to target workbooks! If you need different instances of Excel, then you need to use Windows API to get a handle to the other instances.

Comment: Sorry if I left it ambiguous in my question. But workbooks will not solve my problems. And I don't need an API because I'm after Application.Windows not Windows the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work with multiple windows.

```
Sub wndows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim w As Window

    Set wb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook

    For Each v In wb.Windows
        Set w = v

        'set ws to the active sheet that's in the current window
        Set ws = w.ActiveSheet

        If ws.Name = "Sheet5" Then
            w.Activate
            MsgBox ws.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's an image of my output that I tested:
[image: answer]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This will do exactly what I'm after.